# .py to .exe, three questions

Tags: python, windows, png, module, exe

I want to package a Python script so that it can run as a standalone program on Windows XP and later Windows versions. Now to do this I'm pretty sure I'll have to convert it to an .exe file. I know methods exist, what is the easiest/best method?

Now this is where the question gets a little more advanced. I  also have some modules the program needs in order to run, can I/how do I package those so that my program can utilize them?

All the modules (if it matters):

```
import Tkinter
import time
import re
import pickle
import win32api

from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from time import sleep
```

Next my program also uses PIL in order to display images used in my custom GUI. The thing here is that in order to get the image to run I have to have the complete file path. I have no idea how I'd get this file path on someone else's computer. In short the program requires .png files how do I transfer them so that the program can properly utilize them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/). It's not perfect, but it will convert your script and all dependencies into an executable. I haven't used it in a while, but I believe it makes a directory of dependencies in the directory of the executable. I suspect that you could change the png to a relative path and put it in that directory.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I use [Gui2exe](http://code.google.com/p/gui2exe/) and [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) for a good looking windows installer.

Also [Upx](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) to compress exe/dll.. this keep the unpacked files after Inno setup small.
I dont use Tkinter dont like the look of Tkinter on windows,wxpython is my favorit python gui-toolkit.